# Asyncjs parallel, run in loop

Tags: node.js

I have an array with url's

```
var urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://example.com', 'http://localhost:300'];
```

and a function that reads from url

```
function readUrl(url) {....}
```

i wan't to run the function for all available urls in the array. Is that possible with asyncjs? or any other suggestion.

Comment: Your question could be interpreted as meaning you just want to run some function for each element of an array, which is just `urls.forEach(readUrl)`. Presumably you're interested in doing something more interesting, such as running them in sequence, or running them in parallel and waiting until all they finish, or...?? Also, what does `readUrl` do--does it return a promise, because otherwise, with no callback visible in your example, there will be no way to tell if it's done at all.

Comment: @torazaburo This is resolved over a year ago :D

Comment: dear downvoters care to comment please., at least strange downvote for answer which was accepted..

Comment: @torazaburo as I understood you downvoted for my answer, could you descrie why you have done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible with asyncjs?

yes, it is possible., like this

1.

```
var async = require('async');
var urls  = ['http://google.com', 'http://amazon.com', 'http://bing.com'];

function readUrl(url, next) {
  // some code  
  next(null, result);
}

urls = urls.map(function(url) {
  return function (next) {
    readUrl(url, next);
  };
});

async.parallel(urls, function(err, res) {
  console.log(err, res);
})
```

2.

```
var async = require('async');
var urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://amazon.com', 'http://bing.com'];

function readUrl(url) {
  return true;
}

urls = urls.map(function(url) {
  return function (next) {
    var res = readUrl(url);

    if (res) {
      return next(null, res);
    }

    next('Error');
  };
});

async.parallel(urls, function(err, res) {
  console.log(err, res);
})
```